# Simple Past Tense for duration of time

Tags: simple-past

This is an example of simple past usage I stumbled upon on [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0Ri3QTT41f8):

> Sarah and David talked for two hours.

It is not clear to me why present perfect or past continuous are not used here instead of the past tense, or can all of these tenses be used correctly? *For two hours* specifies a duration of time and *for* is also a signal word used in present perfect tense and past continuous tense.

I thought the past tense is used for finished actions, but in this example, the action was in progress. So why is this sentence correct?

Comment: Talking can be either thought of as a single act or a protracted activity.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand, what does this tell me?

Comment: All the forms you mentioned are okay: "have talked, were talking, talked".

Comment: The simple past is used to talk about an action or event that is finished; that is excluded from the present. It does not matter if the action occurred over a specific/given time period or duration of time: that whole time period or duration *took place in the past*; it did not continue to the present. It is similar to *They talked from 4pm to 6pm* and you say this at 8pm. The duration from 4 to 6pm is over/finished.

Comment: So,  then the sentences   "Sarah and David talked for two hours"  and "Sarah and David were talking for two hours" have the same meaning in this case?

Comment: I might be wrong but I think what you are pointing out is that English lacks an Aorist tense. In Greek one can say 'talked for two hours' and, by using the Aorist, be non-commital about whether the activity is completed or not. In English it is not so. Your sentence, using the English past tense, is stating that the activity has completed in the past.

Answer (score 2):

We use for + duration in different tenses :

- Sarah and David talk for two hours daily. (Regular habit).
- Sarah and David have talked for two hours. (They have just completed their talking.)
- Sarah and David talked for two hours. 
  (Their talking ended in the past.)
- Sarah and David were talking for two hours. 
  (They were talking for two hours and it ended in the past.)
- Sarah and David had been talking for two hours before I came (or, when I came).
  (to say how long they had been talking up to a past moment.)
- Sarah and David will not talk for the next ten days. 
  (They won't talk for a period in future.)

*** But to measure "DURATION UP TO THE PRESENT", we use a present perfect tense :

- Sarah and David have been talking for two hours. 
  (It means their talking started in the past and is still going on.)

Answer (score 0):

The simple past tense is used to express a completed action in the past usually with a reference to a definite time.

Sarah and David talked for two hours yesterday after school.

Where as the present perfect indicates basically an action that has just been finished or is likely to continue even after the time of speaking.

Sarah and David have talked for two hours, now.

The past continuous however, is used to say that one action in the past was in progress when another  action took place.

When I entered the class Sarah and David were talking.

Answer (score -1):

The simple past implies the action took place in the past and is now finished.

If the action (conversation) is still in progress, then I think "Sarah and David had been talking for two hours" would be better.